# Understanding a step of a proof of Markov's inequality

Tags: probability, self-study, probability-inequalities

$X$ is a positive valued random variable, $\theta$ is greater than $1$, $P$ is a probability measure.

Why is the following inequality true:

$$\int_{\theta E(X)}^{+\infty} x dP_{X}(x) \ge \int_{\theta E(X)}^{+\infty} \theta E(X) dP_{X}(x) $$

Comment: I don't know what the complete proof that you are using looks like, but the
simplest proof of Markov's Inequality that I know is that since 
$\alpha^{-1}x\geq\mathbf 1_{\{x\colon x\geq\alpha\}}$ for $\forall x\geq 0$, it follows that
for a _positive_ random variable,
$$E[\alpha^{-1}X]=\frac{\mu_X}{\alpha}\geq E\left[\mathbf 1_{\{x\colon x\geq\alpha\}}\right] = P\{X\geq\alpha\}.$$
The inequality that puzzles you seems to be looking only at the interval $[\alpha,\infty) = [\theta\mu_X,\infty)$ in which case Glen_b's answer tells you exactly what you ask for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note the limits. Since we're integrating from a lower limit of $\theta E(X)$, it must be that $x\geq \theta\, E(X),\: $ for $\:\theta\, E(X) \leq x<\infty$.

From that it should be clear.