# For $Y \geq 0$, prove that $Pr(Y \geq k) \leq E(Y)/k$

Tags: self-study, integral, probability-inequalities, inequality

Let $Y$ be a non-negative random variable, $k$ be any positive constant, show that $Pr(Y \geq k) \leq E(Y)/k$.

My attempt (using integration by parts):

\begin{align}
\int_0^k y \,dF(y) &\leq E(Y) \\
\bigg[yF(y)\bigg]_0^k - \int_0^kF(y)dy &\leq E(Y) \\    
kF(k) - \int_0^kF(y)dy &\leq E(Y) 
\end{align}

The second term on LHS is certainly less than $k$ but that doesn't help because replacing it with $k$ just makes the LHS negative of what I need. I am sure there is simple enough proof but just can't get there.

Comment: Try $E(Y) = \int\limits_{0\le y \lt k} y \,dF(y) + \int\limits_{k\le y \lt \infty} y \,dF(y) \le 0\int\limits_{0\le y \lt k}  \,dF(y) + k\int\limits_{k\le y \lt \infty}  \,dF(y) $

Comment: @Henry: i think there was some small typo in your comment but I got the approach and was able to solve. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes: it certainly should have been $\ge $ rather than $\le$ and there may be others.   This is [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality)

Comment: There is a proof at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130672/understanding-a-step-of-a-proof-of-markovs-inequality

Comment: @Henry: wow this is embarassing!! Didn't know *this* is a famous inequality.